# Multidimensional Array to JSON (and back) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, minecraft

I'm new to Java but am developing a Minecraft plugin, I need to store some data and decided a json would be the easiest since I won't have easy access to a database for the plugin.

I'm attempting to make a basic JSON to (Multidimensional) Array so that I can save my data - however all merges end up appending themselves to the top level "AreaData" tab and not properly creating the array I'm looking for.

Below is parts of the code I'm trying - wondering if a HashMap is even a good idea for this purpose

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AreaHash {

    protected HashMap<String, String> AreaData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public AreaHash(String name, String Owner, Integer X, Integer Y, Integer Z){
        AreaData.put("Name", name);
        AreaData.put("Owner", Owner);
        AreaData.put("X", X.toString());
        AreaData.put("Y", Y.toString());
        AreaData.put("Z", Z.toString());
    }
}
```

```
AreaHash RequestedArea = new AreaHash(Name, Owner.getUniqueId().toString(), location.getBlockX(), location.getBlockY(), location.getBlockZ());
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(RequestedArea);
DataControl.UpdateJson("raid-areas.json", jsonString);
```

**JSON Output**

```
{
  "AreaHash": {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Owner": "gold",
    "X": "10",
    "Y": "15",
    "Z": "-1000"
  }, 
}
```

**What I'm actually looking to produce**

```
{
  "1": [
    "Name": true,
    "Owner": "gold",
    "X": "10",
    "Y": "15",
    "Z": "-1000"
  ],
 "2": [
    "Name": true,
    "Owner": "silver",
    "X": "2110",
    "Y": "15",
    "Z": "-1200"
  ],
 "3": [
    "Name": true,
    "Owner": "test",
    "X": "-110",
    "Y": "70",
    "Z": "-1000"
  ],
}
```

Comment: How do you construct the object with multiple `AreaHash` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Map of `AreaHash` objects then convert it to JSON string.

```
Map<String, AreaHash> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("1", new AreaHash(...));
data.put("2", new AreaHash(...));
data.put("3", new AreaHash(...));

String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(data);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Output (Pretty printed)

```
{
  "1": {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Owner": "gold",
    "X": "10",
    "Y": "10",
    "Z": "0"
  },
  "2": {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Owner": "silver",
    "X": "10",
    "Y": "10",
    "Z": "-10"
  },
  "3": {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Owner": "test",
    "X": "10",
    "Y": "10",
    "Z": "-10"
  }
}
```

Also, take note that your desired output is not valid JSON.

```
[
  "Name": true,
  "Owner": "gold",
  "X": "10",
  "Y": "15",
  "Z": "-1000"
] // this will not parse
```